# How to migrate an onclick event from html to react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I wrote a html code to display cards. Added a modal that open and closes when clicked on an event. I am trying to implement the same in react but not able to do it. I am very new to react stuff hence need your help here to make it compatible in react JS.

In HTML, the onclik event is done through the script but in react, i am trying to write a onclik event inside dev but mostly unsuccessful.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Popoup in javascript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'system-ui', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: .3s linear 0s all;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.container .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/3747155/pexels-photo-3747155.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&lazy=load) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .card .content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .card:hover .contentBx {
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
.container .card .content .contentBx h2 {
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
.container .card .content .contentBx p {
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.container .card .sci {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
}
.container .card .sci li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.container .card:hover .sci li {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
}
.container .card .sci li a {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.blur-filter {
  filter: blur(2px);
}
</style>
<style>
    [modal] {
        opacity: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 120%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        color: white;
        background: #ffffff38;
        backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: 1s linear 0s all;
    }
    [modal="active"] {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0%;
    }
    [modal] > .modal {
        display: contents;
    }
    [modal] > .flexbox_column {
        margin: 0;
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_header {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto 24px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_header > h4 {
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_header > ._close {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_content {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 16px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_content::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 5px;
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_content::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: #e2e2e2; 
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: #9a9a9a; 
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background: #b6b6b6; 
    }
    [modal] > .modal > .modal_content > img {
        max-width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        filter: opacity(0.8);
    }
    [data-modal] {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <!--CARD START-->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="contentBx">
                            <h2>PR1</h2>
                            <p>
                                PR1 is a health related tracker..
                                <a data-modal>See more</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <!--MODAL START-->
                        <div modal>
                            <div class="modal flexbox_column">
                                <div class="modal_header"><h4>MEGA DISCOUNT</h4><span onclick="closeModal(this)" class="_close material-symbols-outlined">expand_more</span></div>
                                <div class="modal_content">
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem!

                                        Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum qui sint voluptatem.

                                        Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem!

                                        Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum qui sint voluptatem.

                                        Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                                    </p>
                                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3756879/pexels-photo-3756879.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Free license from pexels" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--MODAL END-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--CARD END-->
                <!--CARD START-->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="contentBx">
                            <h2>PR1</h2>
                            <p>
                                PR1 is a health related tracker..
                                <a data-modal>See more</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--MODAL START-->
                    <div modal>
                        <div class="modal flexbox_column">
                            <div class="modal_header"><h4>DISCOUNT 50%</h4><span onclick="closeModal(this)" class="_close material-symbols-outlined">expand_more</span></div>
                            <div class="modal_content">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem!

                                    Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum qui sint voluptatem.

                                    Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem!

                                    Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum qui sint voluptatem.

                                    Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                                </p>
                                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3756879/pexels-photo-3756879.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Free license from pexels" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--MODAL END-->
                </div>
                <!--CARD END-->
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    let modalLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-modal]');
    modalLinks.forEach(link => 
        link.addEventListener('click', function() {
            openModal(link)
        })
    );

    function openModal(e) {
        const el = e.closest('.card');
        const modal = el.querySelector('[modal]');
        modal.setAttribute('modal', 'active');
    }

    function closeModal(e) {
        const modal = e.closest('[modal]');
        modal.setAttribute('modal', '');
    }
</script>
</html>
```

React:

```
function App() {
return(
<div>
            <section>
                <div class="container">
                    <!--CARD START-->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="contentBx">
                                <h2>PR1</h2>
                                <p>
                                    PR1 is a health related tracker..
                                    <a data-modal>See more</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <!--MODAL START-->
                            <div modal>
                                <div class="modal flexbox_column">
                                    <div class="modal_header"><h4>MEGA DISCOUNT</h4><span onclick="closeModal(this)" class="_close material-symbols-outlined">expand_more</span></div>
                                    <div class="modal_content">
                                        <p>
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem!
    
                                            Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum qui sint voluptatem.
    
                                            Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem!
    
                                            Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum qui sint voluptatem.
    
                                            Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                                        </p>
                                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3756879/pexels-photo-3756879.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Free license from pexels" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--MODAL END-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--CARD END-->
                    <!--CARD START-->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="contentBx">
                                <h2>PR1</h2>
                                <p>
                                    PR1 is a health related tracker..
                                    <a data-modal>See more</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--MODAL START-->
                        <div modal>
                            <div class="modal flexbox_column">
                                <div class="modal_header"><h4>DISCOUNT 50%</h4><span onclick="closeModal(this)" class="_close material-symbols-outlined">expand_more</span></div>
                                <div class="modal_content">
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem!
    
                                        Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum qui sint voluptatem.
    
                                        Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui repudiandae omnis eos illo numquam sit doloremque officiis ut sint modi sit nulla praesentium? Ut sunt natus non galisum dolor est omnis quae qui voluptatem atque? Ex excepturi natus aut tempore ipsum ea quia rerum non dolores nihil sed exercitationem autem!
    
                                        Est voluptas sint vel enim dolores ea voluptatem suscipit est dolorem ipsum sed recusandae corrupti. Cum perspiciatis nihil aut velit dignissimos aut temporibus itaque est molestias voluptatum qui sint voluptatem.
    
                                        Aut deleniti galisum ut quia quia quo voluptatem soluta et fugit dolores hic consectetur beatae. Ut cupiditate ipsum et doloribus optio et nisi omnis!
                                    </p>
                                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3756879/pexels-photo-3756879.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Free license from pexels" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--MODAL END-->
                    </div>
                    <!--CARD END-->
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>

);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Post a pic of your react code. this is irrelevant

Comment: read the docs properly with composed mind, your both codes are html idk why you calling the 2nd one react.

Comment: actually i am writing the htmls inside the app.js

Answer (score 0):

In React you can implement the Onclick function in a component, like this, `<button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>`. Or you can implement it like this and set up the function somewhere else and call it,
`<button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete Row</button>`. Refer to the React js documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html from the link. Also, post React your code also.

Comment: posted the react code

Comment: there are lot of syntax errors, please follow the react docs and tutorials.